# Existence of particular formula

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus

> Let $A$ and $B$ be propositional formulas such that $A$ has only variables from the sets $\{a_i : i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{b_j : j\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $B$ only has variables from the sets $\{b_j : j\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{c_k : k \in\mathbb{N}\}.$ If $\{A\} \vDash B$ (i.e. for any truth valuation $t$ so that $A^t = 1, B^t = 1$), show that there is a formula $C$ that has only variables from $\{b_j : j \in\mathbb{N}\}$ so that $\{A\} \vDash C$ and $\{C\}\vDash B.$

I suppose I might be able to show this by contradiction. That is, if we assume that for all formulas $C$ with only variables from $\{b_j : j\in\mathbb{N}\},$ either $\{A\}\not\vDash C$ or $\{C\}\not\vDash B.$ However, it seems difficult to arrive at a contradiction from this alone; it might be easier to construct the formula $C,$ but I don't know how to do this with arbitrary formulas. This statement seems true in general; trying it for $A = b_1$ and $B = b_1\vee c_1$, we see that $C = b_1$ works. And trying it for $A = b_1\to (a_1\vee b_1)$ and $B = b_1\to (b_1\vee c_1),$ we see that $C = b_1\to b_1$ works.

Comment: Are you assuming that $\{a_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$, $\{b_j:j\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and $\{c_k: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are pairwise disjoint?

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes. I'm assuming that changes whether the statement is true?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question? What goes wrong if we take $C = B$? Then by assumption $\{A\} \models B$, and we always have $\{B\} \models B$... Should $C$ only have variables in $\{c_j\}$?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor $B$ may contain variables in $\{c_k : k\in\mathbb{N}\},$ which cannot be in $C$. See my last example for a counterexample. Thanks for considering my question though.

Comment: aaaaaah. I read it too quickly. Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Proceed by [structural induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction) on $B$.

As the base case:

- If $\{ A \} \models b_i$, then taking $C = b_i$ works.
- Note $\{ A \} \not \models c_i$, for each $c_i$, so we can proceed vacuously.

As a sample induction step:

Let $B = \varphi \land \psi$.

$$
\begin{align*} 
\{ A \} \models B 
&\Longrightarrow \{ A \} \models \varphi \land \psi \\
&\Longrightarrow \{ A \} \models \varphi \text{ and } \{ A \} \models \psi\\
&\overset{\text{IH}}{\Longrightarrow} \{ A \} \models C_\varphi \text{ and } \{ C_\varphi \} \models \varphi \text{ and } \{ A \} \models C_\psi \text{ and } \{ C_\psi \} \models \psi\\
&\Longrightarrow \{ A \} \models C_\varphi \land C_\psi \text{ and } \{ C_\varphi \land C_\psi \} \models \varphi \land \psi\\
&\Longrightarrow \{ A \} \models C_\varphi \land C_\psi \text{ and } \{ C_\varphi \land C_\psi \} \models B
\end{align*}
$$

Here we used the inductive hypothesis at the marked implication. Notice $C_\varphi \land C_\psi$ uses only variables coming from $\{b_i\}$, since (by induction), each of $C_\varphi$ and $C_\psi$ do.

Do you see how to finish the proof from here?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: to finish the proof, don't I just need to show that this is the case for every possible connective (i.e. for the connectives $\neg, \to, \vee,$ and $\leftrightarrow$)? You've already shown it for the case $B = \varphi\wedge  \omega$.

Comment: That's right. You need to show this for each of the connectives.

Comment: I'm having trouble showing this for $\leftrightarrow$ and $\neg$. So could you provide some hints as to how to deal w/ these cases? For $\to,$ i thought of the following: $\{A\}\vDash \varphi \to \omega$. Then $\{A\}\vDash \neg \varphi$ (in which case the proof for $\neg$ should work) or $\{A\}\vDash \omega$ (in which case we can show that there's a $C_\omega$ only containing variables $b_j$ so that $\{A\}\vDash C_\omega$ and $C_\omega \vDash \omega \Rightarrow C_\omega\vDash \varphi \to \omega$.

Comment: or for $\neg,$ can I change the hypothesis so that in the base case, you prove it for $\{A\}\vDash \neg q_j$?